# DKIM inválida mas existente

Tags: smtp, dkim

Olá, bom, configurei uma maneira para enviar e-mails, configurei o DKIM do servidor no Cpanel corretamente, porém ao testar nas ferramentas de spam acusa DKIM existente porém inválido.

Bom, a questão é, a configuração do meu .php que envia os e-mails esta basicamente assim:

```
$mail->Host = "vps.site.com"; 
$mail->Username = 'suporte@outrosite.com'; //
$mail->Password = 'password'; //
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

A dúvida é, no Host está setado o servidor VPs que possuo, mas a DKIM que gerei foi para o outrosite.com(lá no cpanel), eu fiz certo ou eu teria que ter configurado o DKIM do outrosite.com lá no dominio que está como vps? Estou confuso..

Comment: No cPanel, clique em Email > Autenticação de e-mail. Então você pode tentar desabilitar e habilitar o DKIM. Outra coisa: no host do e-mail, você deveria usar mail.seusite.com, no lugar de vps.site.com.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Ao desabilitar o DKIM, o mesmo continou habilitado, mas agora apresentava uma mensagem como: "O sistema não pode verificar se o servidor é um servidor de nomes autoritativo.." Bom, contatei minha Host e a mesma resolveu o problema! Enfim, essa de de desabilitar e habilitar salvou o jogo. Grato pela resposta!